# How to pass a query/path param in functional/unit test?

Tags: java, spring, rest, functional-testing

I want to write a test for my controller.
And I need to pass a parameter to get().
How can I do it?

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/getClientById")
    public ModelAndView getClientById(Integer id){
        return new ModelAndView("getClientById", "client", clientService.getClientById(id));
    }
```

Test method:

```
given().header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .when()
                .get("getClientById/")//How can I put here an ID ?
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);
```

Comment: whats `given()`?

Comment: Is `id` a QueryParam or a PathParam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include param in your mapping

```
@GetMapping("/getClientById/:clientId")
    public ModelAndView getClientById(@PathParam("clientId") Integer id){
```

or

```
@GetMapping("/getClientById")
    public ModelAndView getClientById(@QueryParam("id") Integer id){
```

and then respectively

```
.get("getClientById/youridvalue")//How can I put here an ID ?
```

and

```
.get("getClientById?id=youridvalue")//How can I put here an ID ?
```

as for second option im think there is a method to include query params but I have no clue what API are you using so cannot elaborate on that (probably not yet)

Comment: Thank you! You helped me very much!